# Qualcomm Artheros WiFi card not detected/stopped working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

Hi my wifi card won't work with ubuntu, its a brand new lenovo laptop and I was previously using fedora workstation but switched back to ubuntu and I can't get my wifi to work.

I've spent a whole day on this but can't seem to make it work, any ideas and suggestions would be appreciated!

EDIT: I think I need to enable 32 MSI vectors clearly that's what's going wrong, but how do I do that? I found this https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-wireless/patch/20211026011605.58615-1-quic_bqiang@quicinc.com/
but I don't really understand it or what's going on.

`dmesg | grep ath11k`

```
[   31.524290] ath11k_pci 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002) 

[   31.524331] ath11k_pci 0000:09:00.0: failed to get 32 MSI vectors, only -28 available 

[   31.524335] ath11k_pci 0000:09:00.0: failed to enable msi: -28

[   31.524344] ath11k_pci: probe of 0000:09:00.0 failed with error -28
```

EDIT2:

```
sudo dmesg | grep ath
```

```
[   19.940159] ath11k_pci 0000:09:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xbe000000-0xbe1fffff 64bit]
[   19.940177] ath11k_pci 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   19.940216] ath11k_pci 0000:09:00.0: failed to get 32 MSI vectors, only -28 available
[   19.940218] ath11k_pci 0000:09:00.0: failed to enable msi: -28
[   19.940226] ath11k_pci: probe of 0000:09:00.0 failed with error -28
[   39.443725] audit: type=1107 audit(1663369812.503:66): pid=1088 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=3482 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=1098 peer_label="unconfined"
[   39.444328] audit: type=1107 audit(1663369812.507:68): pid=1088 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=3482 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=1098 peer_label="unconfined"
[   39.447445] audit: type=1107 audit(1663369812.507:70): pid=1088 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=3482 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=1098 peer_label="unconfined"
[   39.447728] audit: type=1107 audit(1663369812.507:72): pid=1088 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=3482 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=1098 peer_label="unconfined"
```

Comment: Possibly helpful at comment #17. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210923 What is the result of: `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: `Version: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.5`    thanks!, how do I install that firmware though? I'm somewhat green when it comes to linux.

Comment: Although I think our problems are different, I was surprised to find that, after I updated to 23.10, the needed firmware files were present in the right places but were compressed. I documented it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497373/) in case your problem can somehow be related!

Answer (score 1):

You have the latest official version of *linux-firmware.* However, I notice that the sizes and, presumably, the content of the linked firmware files differ. Let's download them and see if the issue is resolved. First, let's back up the existing files:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/ath11k/QCA6390/hw2.0/
sudo mv amss.bin amss.bak
sudo mv m3.bin m3.bak
```

Now, with a working internet connection, download the newer files:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath11k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6390/hw2.0/1.0.1/WLAN.HST.1.0.1-05266-QCAHSTSWPLZ_V2_TO_X86-1/amss.bin
sudo wget https://github.com/kvalo/ath11k-firmware/raw/master/QCA6390/hw2.0/1.0.1/WLAN.HST.1.0.1-05266-QCAHSTSWPLZ_V2_TO_X86-1/m3.bin
```

Reboot and show us:

```
sudo dmesg | grep ath
```

Comment: Ok updated my question with the output

Comment: Hey Chili555, I think I found a solution, could you take a look and let me know what you think https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath11k/installation

Comment: This is simply adding kernel support for ath11k devices, which you already have, and installing firmware, which you already have. I doubt that it will be useful. Is this a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: Oh OK, no no dual boot. Is there anyway I can check to see if its a hardware problem? Cause if so its still under warranty.